# python matrix optimization

Tags: python, math

My input has a shape: `(9, 480, 1)`
Here is my current function:

```
def f(X):
    ordered_max_scorers = np.sort(np.max(X, axis=2), axis=1)
    cd_mat2 = np.array([[0] * len(X)] * len(X), dtype="float64")
    for ind1, score1 in enumerate(ordered_max_scorers):
        for ind2, score2 in enumerate(ordered_max_scorers[:ind1]):
            cognitive_diversity = np.sum((score1 - score2)**2)**(1/2)
            cd_mat2[ind1][ind2] = cognitive_diversity
            cd_mat2[ind2][ind1] = cognitive_diversity
    return cd_mat2
```

And I am trying to optimize this function so that it runs faster: It is called once by an object B within an object A. B is called a few hundred times everytime A runs (about 2 dozen times) if that makes a difference.

I have tried to use a bit of numpy by replacing:

```
cognitive_diversity = np.sum((score1 - score2) ** 2) ** (1/2)
```

with:

```
cognitive_diversity = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(score1 - score2)))
```

But that seems to slow the code down.
I also tried to optimize using numba:

```
@autojit
def temp(x, y): 
    return np.sum((score1 - score2) ** 2) ** (1/2)
```

Which is used for cognitive_diversity again.

```
cognitive_diversity = temp(score1, score2)
```

But it also slowed the code down a lot
If anyone has any suggestions for the speed up or any suggestions how to properly re-write the loop to speed it up that would be amazing!

**EDIT**
Thank you for the assistance. I used it to come up with a slightly different solution.

```
#Std jit optimization
@jit()
def cd_matrix_jit(oms,l_oms,l_oms2,cd_mat2):
    for ind1 in range(l_oms):
        for ind2 in range(l_oms):
            d=0.0
            for i in range(l_oms2):
                d = d + (oms[ind1,i]-oms[ind2,i])**2
            cd_mat2[ind1,ind2] = d**(1/2)
    return cd_mat2
```

Comment: Please use 4 white spaces indents for code intended for others to read; white space around operators is useful too!

Comment: Have you measured where the code is slow? using timeit for instance?

Comment: The main slowdown is due to the repeated calculation of cognitive_diversity. I am just not sure if there is a way not to loop over as much as I do or if there is a better way to optimize the calculation of cognitive_diversity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a few improvements in style:

```
np.array([[0] * len(X)] * len(X), dtype="float64")
```

`len(X)` is 9, `X.shape[0]`.  So this expression is better written as

```
np.zeros((X.shape[0], X.shape[0]))
```

i.e. a 9x9 array of 0s (float the default dtype).

```
cd_mat2[ind1][ind2]
```

can be written as

```
cd_mat2[ind1, ind2]
```

In

```
for ind1, score1 in enumerate(ordered_max_scorers):
        for ind2, score2 in enumerate(ordered_max_scorers[:ind1]):
            cognitive_diversity = np.sum((score1 - score2)**2)**(1/2)
```

you are trying to avoid duplicate calculations by using an upper (or lower) triangle.  That probably isn't worth it with `numpy`.  If you can perform the whole calculation with one expression, rather than loops, it'll be faster even if some values are duplicated.

Something like:

```
cd_mat2 = np.sqrt(np.sum((ordered_max_scorers[:,None] - ordered_max_scorers)**2), axis=1))
```

A sample, `X`, preferably smaller than (9, 480, 1) would let us duplicate your calculations in alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I ended up testing another bunch of solution and ended up going through with a cuda solution for the bigger arrays and otherwise using @guvectorization from numba